# Multiple inserts to the same instance of an immutable data structure in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a data type called `Fork` which is immutable. A `Fork` instance can include one or many instances of another data type `Body`. 
I want to insert a list of `Body` instances into the same `Fork` instance one by one. After each insertion of a `Body`, a new instance of `Fork` will be returned.

I have tried the following code but it gives an error.

```
bodies: Seq[Body] // this is from the constructor 
val fk = Fork(nw, ne, sw, se) // new instance of a Fork is created 
val fkl = bodies.map(b => { val fk: Fork = fk.insert(b) }) // trying to 
// insert a list of Body instances to the same instance of Fork

Error:(131, 46) forward reference extends over definition of value fk
        val fkl=bodies2.map(b=>{ val fk:Fork=fk.insert(b)})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

```
val fkl = bodies.foldLeft(fk)((f,b) => f.insert(b))
```

it will start with original `fk` instance and then for each body `b` will insert body into fork and return updated fork